# MySQL won't allow update despite ON UPDATE CASCADE in foreign key

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have a really weird problem with MySQL where ON UPDATE CASCADE is behaving like ON UPDATE RESTRICT.

I have two MySQL servers, an old Windows Server 2012 and a new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

On both servers, I have three tables -- item, invoice and invoice_box

```
CREATE TABLE `item`  (
  `id` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `idInvoice` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `boxNumber` tinyint(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_item_invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_item_invoice_box` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`, `boxNumber`) REFERENCES `invoice_box` (`idInvoice`, `boxNumber`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `invoice_box`  (
 `idInvoice` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `boxNumber` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_box_invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`) REFERENCES `invoice` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `invoice`  (
 `id` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
)
```

On my old Windows server, if I update the invoice id, the update cascades to the item and invoice_box table successfully.

On the Ubuntu server, it works only if

1. If there are no entries in `item` table, then it cascades to `invoice_box` table correctly.
2. If there are no entries in `invoice_box` table, then it cascades to `item` table correctly.
3. If there are entries in both `item` and `invoice_box` table, then it fails with the following message.

   1452 - Cannot add or update a child row; a foreign key constraint fails (product.item CONSTRAINT fk_item_invoice FOREIGN KEY (idInvoice) REFERENCES invoice(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I don't understand why this won't work exactly the same on both servers.
I did a dump from the Windows server to migrate onto the Ubuntu server, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is your MySQL version under both OS ?

Comment: Code throws an error on my windows box but seems quite happy if either of the 2 fks in items is commented out.

Comment: You should drop `fk_gauge_item_invoice` since it make no sense to drop  `fk_gauge_item_invoice_box` when it's the one that is actually needed to ensure consistent records across all the tables. The wonder here is that this worked in Windows.

Comment: @Alpesh, the versions are MySQL 5.7.20 on Windows and 5.7.21 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Paul, some items are initially assigned only an idInvoice. Another department adds invoice_box entries and assigns items to invoice_box. Therefore, I need fk_gauge_item_invoice to ensure consistency for items not assigned to boxes yet.

Comment: @P.salmon, the structure as it is works perfectly on both my Windows and Ubuntu servers except for the one problem of not allowing invoice id changes when boxes are assigned to items. I cannot go back to the Windows box as it is not scaling well.

Comment: @ghirlekar , So what I understood is like if you update id in invoice table then all the invoceId in all the reference table should also update accordingly am I correct ?, but on ubuntu this is not happening right ?

Comment: @ghirlekar From what you say I presume idInvoice is a value that you assign yourself, so why does it even need to change over time? You can't have both checks and you don't guarantee consistency across all the tables with idInvoice only so I wouldn't keep that one.

Comment: @Alpesh, exactly. It worked perfectly on the old Windows server

Comment: @Paul, I only get through final invoice number just as it is about to be dispatched. Until then, we work on a temporary invoice number. And it worked flawlessly on the Windows server. If this were not possible at all, we would have come up with a different schema altogether, but it's the inconsistent behavior that's far worse.

Answer (score 0):

Code works as coded with the removal of `fk_gauge_item_invoice`

```
drop table if exists i;
drop table if exists ib;
drop table if exists inv;
CREATE TABLE `inv`  (
 `id` varchar(11)  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE `ib`  (
 `idInvoice` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `boxNumber` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  key ib1(idinvoice,boxnumber),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_box_invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`) REFERENCES `inv` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE `i`  (
  `id` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `idInvoice` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `boxNumber` tinyint(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  #CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_item_invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`) REFERENCES `inv` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_item_invoice_box` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`, `boxNumber`) REFERENCES `ib` (`idInvoice`, `boxNumber`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

insert into inv values (1),(2),(3);
insert into ib values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3);
insert into i values (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,3);

MariaDB [sandbox]> update inv set id = 10 where id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from inv;
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 10 |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from ib;
+-----------+-----------+
| idInvoice | boxNumber |
+-----------+-----------+
| 10        |         1 |
| 10        |         2 |
| 2         |         1 |
| 2         |         2 |
| 2         |         3 |
+-----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from i;
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | idInvoice | boxNumber |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 10        |         1 |
| 1  | 10        |         2 |
| 2  | 10        |         1 |
| 2  | 2         |         2 |
| 2  | 2         |         3 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update ib set idinvoice = 20 where idinvoice = 10;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sandbox`.`ib`, CONSTRAINT `fk_gauge_box_invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`idInvoice`) REFERENCES `inv` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

So I'm not clear what your problem is - if you can set up a sql fiddle to demonstrate your issue then that would help.

Comment: @Paul, I cannot do as you suggest since boxNumber in item is nullable if there are no entries in invoice_box. I will create an SQL fiddle and comment with the link.

Comment: @Paul, I ran what you posted on both the Ubuntu box and the Windows one. The update goes through on the Windows machine but not on the Ubuntu one. The MySQL versions 5.7.20 and 5.7.21 are close enough to not warrant such a large difference in behavior.